# Using mutation observer to perform click() on input that pops up dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey, userscripts, mutation-observers

What I am trying to do is run one userscript that clicks the first buy button. And then use another userscript to click the next buy button which comes up as a pop up. The HTML for the second button is only available when the button pops up so I am trying to use a mutation observer to check for the input html and use the click() function.
Here is the current code I have:

```
var dom_observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation) {
    GM_log('function called');
    document.querySelector('#checkout-button').click();
});
var container = document.documentElement || document.body;
GM_log(container);
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree:true};
dom_observer.observe(container, config);
```

The issue is that I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
> at MutationObserver.eval

What I gather from this is that I am still unable to get the html code for the second input button but don't know why as I thought mutation observer would always update the html code I am reading from?

Just a note, this code is from a userscript being run using tampermonkey.

Comment: could you buid a functional sample? it will be easier to help you

Comment: @Frenchy Likely quite hard to make a sample since it is a button that appears after another button is clicked on an external website

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to make a simple example but I am not able to as I can't replicate this issue. It seems like it could be related to the size of the websites html script

Comment: I have also noticed that if I enter "document.querySelector('#checkout-button');" into the console whilst running the userscript, it also returns null. Even after the html script for the input button changes.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing I have noticed, I ran the userscript without the mutation observer and found that the button always returns a value of null when queried using querySelector even when it is in the html script